# Python Error - 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have researched this error and know that it has something to do with the naming of my variables, but I don't see any variables in my code that are "magic words". What am I missing? Thanks!

```
def shrink_inv (p,r,n,t):
    return p(1+r/n)**n*t

shrink_inv(10,-0.1,1,1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
return p(1+r/n)**n*t
```

You are missing an operator after `p` - it's currently interpreted as a function call.

Comment: This is right. Python thinks 'p' is a function as it currently is.